# Setting complex property values using reflection in c#

Tags: c#

I've read through several questions similar to my problem, but my understanding of the concepts is lacking to where the general answers don't match up enough to answer my specific question, to wit:

I have a domain object I instantiate from a db call:

```
public class dbRecord {
    public decimal RecordCode {get;set;}
    public string  FirstName {get; set;}
    ... 40 more fields ....
}
```

I have another stored procedure call that pulls column metadata (not shown) that I need to merge with the first object and create:

```
public class ViewRecord {
    public MetadataRecord<decimal> RecordCode {get;set;}
    public MetadataRecord<string> FirstName {get; set;}
    ... 40 more fields ....
}
```

The MetadataRecord object is this:

```
public class MetadataRecord<T>{
    public T ColumnValue {get;set;}
    public bool IsFrozen {get;set;}
    public string ValidatorFieldName {get;set;}
}
```

I could create the ViewRecord object via a manual mapping like this:

```
var newFile = new ViewRecord();
newFile.RecordCode.ColumnValue = dbRecord.RecordCode;
... 40 more times ...
```

But I thought I could use reflection to build this out:

```
var startFile = ...dbRecord from db result...
var newFile = new ViewRecord();
foreach (var startProp in startFile.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    foreach (var newProp in newFile.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        if (startProp.Name == newProp.Name) {
              PropertyInfo valProp = typeof(MetadataRecord<>).GetProperty("ColumnValue");
                    var data = startProp.GetValue(startFile, null);
                    valProp.SetValue(valProp, data, null);
        }
     }
}
```

This works all the way up to where I try and set the value, and I get the following exception:

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Can anyone help me figure out a different/better way to make this work? The whole issue is one where we have field-level metadata that I have to add to the db records at runtime, which has led me down this rabbit hole!

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE
Ok I see now, the newPropType has to be instantiated and assigned:

```
var instanceType = Activator.CreateInstance(newPropType);
...
valProp.SetValue(instanceType, data);
newProp.SetValue(newFile, instanceType);
```

Thanks for your answer, Andrew!

Props also to kkilton@gmail.com for giving me the hint on Activator.CreateInstance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to fully specify the generic type of the metadata property.

```
PropertyInfo valProp = typeof(MetadataRecord<>).MakeGenericType(startProp.PropertyType).GetProperty("ColumnValue");
```

or, more readably:

```
Type newPropType = typeof(MetadataRecord<>).MakeGenericType(startProp.PropertyType);
PropertyInfo valProp = newPropType.GetProperty("ColumnValue");
```

And you need to use the metadata object in the value setting line:

```
var metadataObj = newProp.GetValue(newFile);
valProp.SetValue(metadataObj, data, null);
```